# Guidelines to request information?

Tags: support, help-pages

Is there a place to review guidelines and rules for asking questions within this app? Aside from being respectful and courteous of course.

Answer (score 1):

If by "this app" you mean Stack Overflow, see:

- site tour: https://superuser.com/tour
- help pages: https://superuser.com/help/asking
- the meta forum: https://meta.superuser.com/

Note that Stack Overflow is a sub-site of the overall Stack Exchange site. Every sub-site has its own rules and guidelines, so visit their websites before posting.

Comment: I hope you mean Super User :)

Comment: Originally that was "every site in the Stack Overflow network", because I couldn't remember what the network was called this week. Apparently migration doesn't preserve [edit history](http://superuser.com/posts/1180271/revisions)...

Comment: Technically the "rules for asking questions" within Super User's help does *not* cover the "rules for asking questions" for *each and every Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow website*. Also, I've never heard of the Stack Exchange *network* referred to collectively as "Stack Overflow"; when I read "Stack Overflow" I think of the site that can be reached at http://stackoverflow.com or the *company*, but **not** the network. The [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/) announcing the change supports this 100%.

Comment: Also, *even if* they decided they wanted to change the term for the network from "Stack Exchange network" to "Stack Overflow network", you're still missing the term "network". Using the unqualified term "Stack Overflow" should always unambiguously refer to either *that specific site* and *not* all the other sites in the network (whatever the network's name is); or the *company* that employs people, etc. Since this post has nothing to do with the company, the term "network" is definitely needed to distinguish it from you answering a meta.SU post about the rules on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: As I understand it - we're still part of the stack exchange network, The company is Stack Overflow

Comment: Only as a trading name. It still says Stack Exchange at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Someone ironically (or unironically?) our standard poor quality question mod message has a lot of what you need.

- An overview of [how our system works](https://superuser.com/tour)
- A brief [guide on how to ask questions](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)
- A short summary of [questions we permit](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)
- Help on [formatting your questions](https://superuser.com/editing-help)

I'd start by saying a good question gives the person reading it *enough information* to make a reasonable guess to how to solve your problem. Formatting it in a readable fashion makes things simpler. Sticking to what you *need* and adding things on is fine. It makes a lot of sense to search first and see how similar well received questions are structured too

Read comments, build your question and be at least a little patient and you'll be fine.